# Send long SMS with AWS SNS using Go and GSM or ASCII encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

Hi I read on AWS SNS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html) that SMS messages sent using GSM-7 encoding can have 160 characters or 140 on ASCII or 70 on UC-2. The SNS will select the best encoding for the message. I'm using the following code to send SMS messages and it always selects the UC-2 encoding breaking my messages in two or more parts. There is a way to force SNS use ASCII or GSM encoding ?

```
svc := sns.New(newSession())

if _, err = svc.Publish(&sns.PublishInput{
    Message:     aws.String(content),
    PhoneNumber: aws.String(number),
    MessageAttributes: map[string]*sns.MessageAttributeValue{
        "DefaultSMSType": {
             DataType: aws.String("String"),
             StringValue: aws.String("Transactional")},
        },
}); err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

Comment: What is the text of the message you are trying to send?

Comment: Hi Michael it's plain text without special characters: Obrigado por comprar no Xxxxxx. Segue o link para seu boleto bancario http://www.xxxxx.com/s/aA0sf

Comment: Hm. That's not the real text. Try pasting the real text into [this tool](https://chadselph.github.io/smssplit/) and it will tell you if there are characters that force UCS-2.

Comment: Hi Michael o typed my text message (the real one) on the tool and the message is GSM and shouldn't be splited, but the amazon SNS uses UC2 always and splits my message on Go SKD.